# Bus to Landmannalaugar late May/ early June

Tags: buses, hiking, iceland

I want to hike from Landmannalaugar to Þórsmörk between 28/05 to 03/06. From what I could gather roads there might not be passable yet. We will have a 4x4 car, but do not want to travel twice so one way of the hike we would want to be driven and then walk down to the car. [This](https://www.re.is/iceland-on-your-own) website suggests that bus will not begin running until 12th of June. 
What is the likelihood of the road being open those dates and what alternative bus companies can we find?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 'not begin running until 12th of June'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely **the roads won't be open yet**, according to the Icelandic authority, which publishes statistics on such matters. The median date for opening Landmannalaugar is [June 17](http://www.vegagerdin.is/vefur2.nsf/Files/Opnun_fjallvega_en_2016/$file/Opnun_fjallvega_en_2016.pdf), the earliest date being May 31 so you're short on luck it seems.

If the roads are closed, I don't think any bus company will attempt to go there. I've checked a few bus companies ([here](http://trex.is/landmannalaugar/), [here](http://www.nat.is/re/bus_stop_rek_landml_rek.%20re-htm.htm), [here](http://www.hostel.is/Tours/ClassicDayTours/Landmannalaugarbybus/) and [here](https://www.getyourguide.com/reykjavik-l30/landmannalaugar-by-bus-t2015/)) and all seem to start operating around mid-June, [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Landmannalaugar#Get_in) says the same.

As an aside I recommend [this website](http://www.road.is/travel-info/road-conditions-and-weather/south-iceland/south1.html) for checking road and weather conditions in Iceland, it's extremely important you don't underestimate Icelandic weather when driving there.

Comment: Think I will ask a question where can I actually hike in Iceland, assuming all F roads are closed.

Comment: @mega_creamery can't help with hiking, but I drove there so I have an idea what it's like, F roads are tough but Iceland is definitely worth it !

Comment: I wish I did more research before booking flights. I hoped that by going not in the high season would mean just being more cold, but everything else being cheaper. Could have not guessed that more than 90% of the Island would be inaccessible, sigh.

Comment: @mega_creamery I met a couple of hikers/campers (in June) who told me they've been there since March, so it seems doable, driving will be tough though.